# shifting/aligning nodes with pst-tree

Tags: linguistics, pst-tree

The following code produces nice trees with `pst-trees`. I have to gloss the leaves of the tree, so I put tabular environments in there and added the glosses. The problem is that the code does not align the nodes towards the top but centers them. This means that the N above David is between `is` and `AUX`. But it should be at the hight of `is` as in the left example. Is this possible?
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{pst-tree}

\psset{nodesep=5pt}
\psset{linewidth=0.5pt}

\makeatletter
\def\tree{\@ifnextchar[{\@tree}{\@tree[top]}}
\def\@tree[#1]#2#3{%
  \renewcommand\psedge{\ncdiag[arm=0,angleA=270,angleB=90,linewidth=.5pt]}
  \pstree[levelsep=*2.8ex,nodesep=3pt,treesep=.5cm]{\TR[name=#1]{\small #2}}{#3}}


\def\le{\@ifnextchar[{\@le}{\@le[lex]}}
\def\@le[#1]#2{\renewcommand\psedge{\ncdiag[arm=0,angleA=270,angleB=90,linewidth=.5pt]}
               \TR[name={#1}]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}


\tree[a]{IP}{%
  \tree{NP}{\tree{N$'$}{%
    \tree{N}{\le{David}}}}
  \tree[b]{I$'$}{%
    \tree[c]{I}{\le{is}}
    \tree[d]{VP}{\tree[e]{V$'$}{\tree[f]{V}{\le{yawning}}}}}}%
\hfill
\tree[a]{IP}{%
  \tree{NP}{\tree{N$'$}{%
    \tree{N}{\le{David\\David}}}}
  \tree[b]{I$'$}{%
    \tree[c]{I}{\le{is\\\textsc{aux}}}
    \tree[d]{VP}{\tree[e]{V$'$}{\tree[f]{V}{\le{yawning\\gloss}}}}}}%


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the option[t]$ to the`tabular`_ environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-tree}

\psset{nodesep=5pt}
\psset{linewidth=0.5pt}

\makeatletter
\def\tree{\@ifnextchar[{\@tree}{\@tree[top]}}
\def\@tree[#1]#2#3{%
  \renewcommand\psedge{\ncdiag[arm=0,angleA=270,angleB=90,linewidth=.5pt]}
  \pstree[levelsep=*2.8ex,nodesep=3pt,treesep=.5cm]{\TR[name=#1]{\small #2}}{#3}}

\def\le{\@ifnextchar[{\@le}{\@le[lex]}}
\def\@le[#1]#2{\renewcommand\psedge{\ncdiag[arm=0,angleA=270,angleB=90,linewidth=.5pt]}
               \TR[name={#1}]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tree[a]{IP}{%
  \tree{NP}{\tree{N$'$}{%
    \tree{N}{\le{David}}}}
  \tree[b]{I$'$}{%
    \tree[c]{I}{\le{is}}
    \tree[d]{VP}{\tree[e]{V$'$}{\tree[f]{V}{\le{yawning}}}}}}%
\hfill
\tree[a]{IP}{%
  \tree{NP}{\tree{N$'$}{%
    \tree{N}{\le{David\\David}}}}
  \tree[b]{I$'$}{%
    \tree[c]{I}{\le{is\\\textsc{aux}}}
    \tree[d]{VP}{\tree[e]{V$'$}{\tree[f]{V}{\le{yawning\\gloss}}}}}}%

\end{document}
```

[image]